# White screen when trying to use useNavigate() react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have tried using navigate() to go to the profile page but when I reload my react app it's just a white screen but I have defined the path '/profile'?

```
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{height: '100%', minHeight: '100vh', backgroundColor: '#FFFDC8'}}>
      <h1>Auction App</h1>
      <Button variant="contained">Auctions</Button>
      <Button variant="contained">My Auctions</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => navigate("/profile")}>Profile</Button>
        
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Auctions />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/auctions' element={<Auctions />} />
          <Route path='/auction/:auctionId' element={<AuctionItem />} />
          <Route path='/my-auctions' element={<MyAuctions />} />
          <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

The `App` component is rendering the `Router` that is providing the routing context, so `App` itself can't use the `useNavigate` hook since it's ***outside*** the router.

## Solution

I am assuming that `Router` is *really* one of the higher-level routers (*`BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, etc*). Move the `Router` higher in the ReactTree than the `App` component in order to provide a routing context to `App` and allow proper `useNavigate` hook usage.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

App

```
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFDC8'
      }}
    >
      <h1>Auction App</h1>
      <Button variant="contained">Auctions</Button>
      <Button variant="contained">My Auctions</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => navigate("/profile")}>
        Profile
      </Button>
     
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Auctions />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/auctions' element={<Auctions />} />
        <Route path='/auction/:auctionId' element={<AuctionItem />} />
        <Route path='/my-auctions' element={<MyAuctions />} />
        <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean having <Router> <App /> </Router> in a separate file?

Comment: @GrandSkunk Whatever the separate file is that is rendering the `App` component. In a lot of cases it's the `index.js` file that is using `ReactDOM` or `root.render` now with React 18. Move the `Router` component higher than `App` so it is rendered within a routing context.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you had `BrowserRouter` .

```
 <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Auctions />} />
       <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
       <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
       ........
       ........
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: The screen just goes white when I have 'const navigate = useNavigate();' in the function

Comment: Use app.js for only Routers.